# Bespoke Docker setup in WSL2

Tags: php, docker, wsl-2, bespoke.js

Just started a six-month contract where the entire system appears to be a mono-repo. Docker PS PORTS: 0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp (aye, one container)

Everyone seems to be using Macs (the company issues them to employees) which a few years ago would be groovy as my Mac (2015) was made when Steve Jobs was around.

So if they want SequelPro (ETA: maybe not unless they actually open  db port) or some elasticsearch app, Postman (same thing with ports) or what have you they're all set. I installed what seems to be a good MySQL workbench in WSL2 but of course it doesn't right now detect any DB's.

So is there any half-decent approach where I can configure access from Windows? Or should I be looking for a 1998-2000+ Macbook Pro?

I have been using WSL2 Docker for some years. Nginx/Apache (in their very own containers) would have some open port, as would the app. I likely could get them to mod the Dockerfiles (no docker-compose to be found) to expose some ports yet I seem to recall - maybe WSL1 - you could basically open everything. I don't want to be the new guy who asks for changes just because I'm using WSL so if I can make some change just on my machine I'm willing to do it.

I was thinking of at least opening some ports to WSL2 so I could use Workbench (sure I can already exec into the container and run mysql) and as I just started I don't know how to see my updates so opening port 80 and running some browser will be useful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You really want to be very specific with your question. If the only issue you're having is accessing a MySQL database from Windows then I would recommend using HeidiSQL in Windows and configuring the ports correctly. It works with most major RDMS. You have the host on 0.0.0.0, so is your Docker running on your Windows machine? What's the relevance of your Mac being from 2015? SequelPro stills works, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try going Linux. M$ and Apple (although a newer Pro in the arsenal would be nice) aren't providing anything this projects needs.

And WSL could only be a constant hassle. Even just last week I "refreshed" windows and not one of my docker repos worked right off and even now only the PostgreSQL apps running as they should.

I've got a Sandisk 99D Terrabyte SSD that I've done little with. I reckon dual booting Linux off that will be a good solution.

I know there are issues with correctly setting up bootloaders and other partitions (besides re-installing this app) so I'll leave this question open a few more hours in case someone has tips or I have other questions. TIA!